# Limit of $a(n+1)-a(n)$, where $a(n)=n^{n^{-1/n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sequence $$a(n)=n^{n^{-1/n}}$$ The values of $a(n)$ for $n$ from $1$ to $12$, to three decimal places, are:
$$1.000\ \ 1.632\ \ 2.141\ \ 2.665\ \ 3.210\ \ 3.777\ \ 4.365\ \ 4.970\ \ 5.591\ \ 6.227\ \ 6.877\ \ 7.539$$
But what is really interesting is the sequence 
$$
b(n)=a(n+1)-a(n) = (n+1)^{(n+1)^{-1/(n+1)}} -n^{n^{-1/n}}
$$ whose values for $n$ from $1$ to $11$ are:
$$0.632\ \ 0.509\ \ 0.524\ \ 0.545\ \ 0.567\ \ 0.588\ \ 0.605\ \ 0.621\ \ 0.636\ \ 0.650\ \ 0.662$$
Thus, after $n=2$, $b(n)$ starts to grow strictly monotonically, but I do not know is this behavior holds everywhere after $n=11$? Also, it comes as a surprise that $b(n)$, although very simply defined and generated from relatively simple sequence $a(n)$, shows such a regular grow.

Yes, I expected to see interesting behavior, but it would be really nice if $b(n)$ had a limit other then $0$ or $+ \infty$, if it converges at all? At first glance I thought that $b(n)\to0$ but experimental data suggest something different.

> So, is the sequence $(b(n))$ convergent and, if it is, what is its limit?

More experimental data is also highly welcomed, with or without proof.

Comment: I don't understand the exponent in definition of $a_n$. What is it? $n\cdot -\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @RobertZ No, it is $n^{\frac {-1}{n}}$

Comment: @RobertZ If it was that yours then we would have $a(n)=\frac{1}{n}$, right?

Comment: Yes. Maybe its better to write $n^{n^{-1/n}}$

Comment: @RobertZ That is ambigous because exponentiation is not associative, we need parentheses.

Comment: @RobertZ Now I edited to write it as intended, we first do the calculation in parentheses and then exponentitate n with that result.

Comment: I calculated $b_n$ for n = 100,000. The last  six results are   0.999769100919366,
   0.999769103073049,
   0.999769105226733,
   0.999769107264001,
   0.999769109417684,
   0.999769111454953, so it looks like it is converging to 1 very slowly. I calculated it again for n = 200,000 and the last results are    0.999985484872013
   0.999985487898812,
   0.999985488131642,
   0.999985485104844,
   0.999985488364473,
   0.999985485337675

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha $b(n)$ converges to 1.
Expression for your convenience: 
$$
 (n+1)^{1/(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}} -n^{1/n^{1/n}}
$$

Comment: @1524 Does $\alpha$ give steps of the calculation?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin unfortunately not for me, no.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n%5En%5E(-1%2Fn)+,+n+tends+to+infinity  shows $n^{n^{-1/n}}\approx n-\ln(n)^2$ for large $n$. Maybe this helps

Comment: Even better, according to Wolfram alpha, we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n-\ln(n)^2-n^{n^{-1/n}}=0$$ This implies easily the limit $1$ of the above expression, but I have no clue how to show the limit $0$

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Comment: @Did Hi Did, I was thinking about maybe half an hour or hour ago about you and when I logged in MSE I saw a notification and it was this comment of yours. I guess we are mind-connected through physical space.

Comment: Sure... And what about the question in my comment?

Comment: @Did I do not understand your answer yet.

Comment: OK. Elected a plan of action about this, after 33 days? Zero comment on the subject yet, right?

Answer (score 0):

> *Basic results required:*
>
> - $e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$ when $x\to0$
> - $(\log n)^4\ll n$ when $n\to\infty$

Note that $a(n)=n^{n^{-1/n}}$ is $a(n)=ne^{-c(n)\log n}$ with $c(n)=1-n^{-1/n}=1-e^{-d(n)}$ with $d(n)=\frac1n\log n$, and in particular $d(n)=o(1)$.

Hence, $c(n)=d(n)+O(d(n)^2)$ and $a(n)=n\left(1-c(n)\log n+O(c(n)^2\log ^2 n)\right)$ thus $$a(n)=n-nd(n)\log n+O(nc(n)^2\log ^2 n)=n-\log^2 n+o(1)$$ where the error term is $o(1)$ because $$nc(n)^2\log ^2 n\sim\tfrac1n(\log n)^4\to0$$ hence $$a(n+1)-a(n)=1+\log^2(n+1)-\log^2n+o(1)=1+o(1)$$ that is, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a(n+1)-a(n)\right)=1$$ The intermediary result above, more precise than the desired conclusion, is that

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a(n)-n+\log^2 n\right)=0$$